# Symbolic links in MacOSX with scripts

Tags: macos, symlink

I have a script in one folder, that at the same time uses other executables at the same folder.

For example, in `~/scripts/`:

myscript:

> `./mybinfile argument`

And I want to make a symbolic link to the script (to `~/bin/`). But if I use `ln -s abs_path_to/myscript ~/bin/myscript`, it tries to search `mybinfile` in `~/bin`, not in `~/scripts`. I do not want to add nothing to my `$PATH`. How can I make the script to look `.` in `~/scripts`? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use full paths when generating your symlinks?

```
ln -s ~/scripts/myscript ~/bin/myscript
```

Comment: If I do that, when I run `$ myscript` it says: `./mybinfile: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Can you post an example of your script?  Also is ~/bin in your path?

Comment: I made an example, where it happens.
I have 2 folders, `a` and `b`. In `a`:
myscript:
`./myotherscript`
myotherscript:
`echo "Hello world!"

And, I make:
`ln -s ~/a/myscript ~/b/myscript`

When I try to run `./myscript` in `b`, I get the error.

Comment: If ~/bin or /Users/username/bin is in your path you should not have to put ./mybinfile just mybinfile.  If ~/bin or /Users/username/bin is not in your path just call it in the start of the script:

Comment: PATH=$PATH:/Users/username/bin

Comment: `~/bin` is already in my `$PATH`. That is not the problem. The problem is that when I try to execute `./myscript` in `b` it says `./myotherscrip: No such file or directory`, please notice it complains about `myotherscript` not `myscript`.

In other words, I want that for `myscript`, `.` means `a/`, not `b/`.

Comment: Ok, when you run myscript ./myotherscript what directory are you in and what directory is myotherscript in?  Also is myotherscript chmod 755?

Comment: The problem results when I am in `b/`, which only contains the symbolic link to `a/myscript`, and try to run `./myscript`.
And yes, `myotherscript` is executable, it's `chmod 755`.